# bmatrix with individual column alignment specifier

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I know that I already found this, but I am not sure where, so I ask it here.

How can I individually specify the number and alignment of a bracket matrix using `bmatrix`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
A = \left[%
\begin{array}[@{}lcr@{}]
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{displaymath}

% Achieve the same as above

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{bmatrix}[lcr]
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg I already found it. But know I don't remember where. And there was a comment from you saying this would be good addon to `amsmath`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is what I was trying to find. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: The `bmatrix*` environment of `mathtools` allows for specifying only a global alignment for all columns.

Comment: Yes. But I was looking for that question, where I can define individual alignments.

Comment: If you want to specify the individual alignments for a `bmatrix`, then it's far easier to define your own environment which emulates `array`.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I didn't want to do that because I wanted to keep the definition as before with a little improvements that does not require changing the full document itself for that new redefinition.